# How to find out if a translation exists?

Tags: translation, publishing

Is it possible to find out if a translation exists?
Books since 1966 have an ISBN (International Standard Book Number), so a book can be traced to the publisher, and then in theory to the copyrightholder, who should than have knowledge of various translations.
For public domain books, there is probably historic data on translations. Who keeps track and how of translations after the book entered public domain, I have no idea.

Is any of this information public somewhere?

In this specific case I am trying to find out if a Dutch translation exists of the Croatian book 'Price iz Davnine' by Ivana Brlic Mazuranic.
This book was first published in 1916, and has been translated to several languages.

Comment: https://www.worldcat.org/advancedsearch lets you specify author's name and language of publication .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Worldcat, I often find that Goodreads does a good job of coalescing translations of a work under the "other editions" tab.¹

That said, neither Goodreads nor Worldcat are showing a Dutch translation of *Priče iz Davnine*. This doesn't mean that a Dutch edition doesn't exist, but it seems unlikely, since neither Croatian nor Dutch represent big markets and I would guess that the sum total of books translated from Croatian to Dutch (or vice versa) is probably small enough to fit on a single bookcase if not a single shelf of that bookcase.

I'd also note that the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croatian_Tales_of_Long_Ago) for *Priče iz Davnine* lists translations of the work but shows no Dutch translation.²

---

1. I did see that there were two English translations of the book that weren't subsumed in the main entry for *Priče iz Davnine*, but I didn't see any Dutch titles showing up under Brlić-Mažuranić's name.
2. Interestingly, the Croatian, Bosniak, Serbian and Ukrainian pages for the work do not list translations (with the Bosniak, Serbian and Ukrainian pages appearing to be translations of the Croatian).